# Is it thread safe to get context of NSManagedObject instance?

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, thread-safety

I.e. to access the `managedObjectContext` property of NSManagedObject from other thread? For example:

```
class StoredObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var interestProperty: String
}

------- somewhere on background -------

let context = storedObject.managedObjectContext // is it safe?
context.perform { [storedObject] in
    // do something with interestProperty
}

---------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why would you need this? `NSManagedObjectContext` is not thread safe, so what would you do with it on another thread?

Comment: legacy) it's known that `objectID` property is thread safe, but I'm not sure about `managedObjectContext `. Anyway there wasn't raised any exception, even with `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectContext` is not thread safe. Even if you grab the instance of such an object, using it on a different thread might lead to undefined behaviour.

This is specified in the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background) (emphasis mine):

> Core Data is designed to work in a multithreaded environment. However, not every object under the Core Data framework is thread safe. To use Core Data in a multithreaded environment, ensure that:
>
> - **Managed object contexts are bound to the thread (queue) that they are associated with upon initialization.**
> - Managed objects retrieved from a context are bound to the same queue that the context is bound to.

So while reading the `managedObjectContext` property might be thread safe, as that property is readonly, you will not be able to use it without risking race conditions. And you also need to take into consideration the lifetime of the managed object, as unless properly retained, you might end up asking a deallocated managed object for its context.

Comment: Nice answer. However, since Managed Objects can be in a "faulted" state, I wouldn't bet too much on the "readonly" property:  it _might_ be set after initialisation of that proxy, when it will be realised. And if this is the case, or can be the case, accessing such readonly properties aren't thread safe. Without knowing the source code, we don't know ;)

Comment: Good point @CouchDeveloper about the "faulted" state, one more reason to avoid consuming the managed context. Theoretically one shouldn't even need to do this, the natural direction is managed context -> managed object, not the vice versa.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Faulting applies to properties that are read from the persistent store. The managed object context isn't one of those properties, so faulting doesn't affect whether it's safe to access.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "deallocated" managed object. Managed objects can become faults but it doesn't mean they deallocate. They do exist and you can access them. The primary concern with `NSManagedObject.managedObjectContext` that it can turn `nil` if the object is deassociated from the context. But if you can guarantee that it doesn't happen, then there is absolutely nothing wrong with grabbing the context and performing work on it.

Comment: @BenAffleck instances of `NSManagedObject` are regular Objective-C objects, and such they have a lifetime, which involves allocation and deallocation (and retains/releases between).

Comment: @Cristik so what? as long as you retain the instance of `NSManagedObject` it cannot deallocate on its own. Same rules apply in Swift virtually for anything except `struct` which are passed by value.

Comment: @BenAffleck yes, exactly, that's why I said in the answer `unless properly retained`

Comment: @Cristik fair enough, although memory management is not really a part of that question, any object may become deallocated if you don't hold a strong reference to it, i.e if you use `unowned` but that's black magic, people use `weak` more often which is safe. All in all, I think passing the `NSManagedObjectContext` around is more common than trying to access it from managed object, but I imagine there may be rare cases where that's useful.

Comment: @BenAffleck the point is that one should not attempt to circulate objects that are not thread safe, within multiple threads. And neither `NSManagedObject`, nor `NSManagedObjectContext`, are thread safe. And that's because race conditions can occur, race conditions which in 99% (if not more) of the cases are related to memory access and management.

Comment: @Cristik agree. Ideally the one should pass the object ID around and then construct the managed object when needed.

Comment: @BenAffleck but what is the difference between grabbing `managedObjectContext` or `objectID` If the both of them can be `nil` if the object is deassociated from the context? Btw yes, in my case it's guaranteed that it doesn't happen

Comment: @aimelda only `objectID` is safe to be used in multiple thread, now regarding the possibility of being nil, it's your responsibility to prevent this. Anyway, once you queried a managed object for it's id, and you got a valid value, you can freely circulate it within your app, assuming you keep strong references to it.

Comment: @TomHarrington Thanks for this info, that only "store" properties get affected by the faulted state. I also was viewing "thread-safety" from a more general point of view, not just related to Managed Objects:  reading properties from thread A (without synchronisation) is only thread-safe IFF the object's property has been set in the initialiser executing on any thread AND has NOT been mutated till the read. If it will be mutated from another thread B, read from A is not thread-safe, even if the property gets the same value. So, "read only" from A cannot make any guarantees about thread-safety.